# GroupBy generating wrong OrderBy query

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following query:

```
            var trains = queryableTrains.Select(t => new TrainDto
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Prefix = t.Prefix,
                Color = t.Color,
                PlannedMovements = t.TrainMovementPlans
                    .Where(p => trackCircuitIds.Contains(p.TrackCircuitId) && p.TimeStamp >= start && p.TimeStamp <= end)
                    .Select(p => new TrainMovementDto
                    {
                        SgfId = null,
                        Prefix = t.Prefix,
                        BlockSectionId = p.TrackCircuit.TrackCircuitGroupId ?? p.TrackCircuitId,
                        Timestamp = p.TimeStamp,
                        IsExit = false
                    })
                    .GroupBy(o => o.BlockSectionId)
                    .Select(o => o.First())
                    //.OrderBy(d => d.Timestamp)
                    .ToList(),
                   // ...
```

It's a lot to code to share everything so I will share the concept hoping it helps.
Basically my data model is as follows:

- `Train` has several `PlannedMovements`
- I want to use `GroupBy` to remove "duplicates", i.e., movements that has the same `BlockSectionId` (after the projection).

When I run the above code, even with the `OrderBy` commented, I get the following exception:

```
[17:00:55 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[@_outer_Prefix='?' (Size = 4000), @__start_2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @__end_3='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @_outer_Id2='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT @_outer_Prefix AS [Prefix], COALESCE([p.TrackCircuit3].[YRCTCGID], [p5].[YSBTRCID]) AS [BlockSectionId], [p5].[YSBTIMES], CAST(0 AS bit) AS [IsExit], [p.TrackCircuit3].[YRCTCGID], [p5].[YSBTRCID]
FROM [YSBPLTMT] AS [p5]
INNER JOIN [YRCTRCIT] AS [p.TrackCircuit3] ON [p5].[YSBTRCID] = [p.TrackCircuit3].[YRCTRCID]
WHERE (([p5].[YSBTRCID] IN ( _HUGE_GROUP_I_HAVE_TO_CHANGE_FOR_A_JOIN_ ) AND ([p5].[YSBTIMES] >= @__start_2)) AND ([p5].[YSBTIMES] <= @__end_3)) AND (@_outer_Id2 = [p5].[YSBTRAID])
ORDER BY COALESCE([p.TrackCircuit3].[YRCTCGID], [p5].[YSBTRCID]), [BlockSectionId]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:f68441e8-baa8-4c16-aa66-0cae875ba173
Error Number:169,State:1,Class:15
[17:00:55 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'GCO.Data.GcoContext'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._InjectParameters[TElement](QueryContext queryContext, IEnumerable`1 source, String[] parameterNames, Object[] parameterValues)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._GroupBy[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:f68441e8-baa8-4c16-aa66-0cae875ba173
Error Number:169,State:1,Class:15
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._InjectParameters[TElement](QueryContext queryContext, IEnumerable`1 source, String[] parameterNames, Object[] parameterValues)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._GroupBy[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:f68441e8-baa8-4c16-aa66-0cae875ba173
Error Number:169,State:1,Class:15
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
[17:00:55 INF] Executed action GCO.App.Controllers.MareysChart.MareysChartController.GetInitialData (GCO.App) in 331.5571ms
[17:00:55 INF] Executed endpoint 'GCO.App.Controllers.MareysChart.MareysChartController.GetInitialData (GCO.App)'
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
[17:00:55 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._InjectParameters[TElement](QueryContext queryContext, IEnumerable`1 source, String[] parameterNames, Object[] parameterValues)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider._GroupBy[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier`2 )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at GCO.App.MareysChart.Services.TrainService.GetTrains(DateTime start, DateTime end, List`1 trackCircuitIds) in C:\Projects\VSTS\GCO_server-dotnet\GCO\GCO\MareysChart\Services\TrainService.cs:line 66
   at GCO.App.Controllers.MareysChart.MareysChartController.GetInitialData(Int64 tabId, String dateUtcString) in C:\Projects\VSTS\GCO_server-dotnet\GCO\GCO\Controllers\MareysChart\MareysChartController.cs:line 269
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at GCO.App.Middlewares.UserInfoMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, GcoContext dbContext, ILuwakUserInfoAccessor userInfoAccessor) in C:\Projects\VSTS\GCO_server-dotnet\GCO\GCO\Middlewares\UserInfoMiddleware.cs:line 94
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:f68441e8-baa8-4c16-aa66-0cae875ba173
Error Number:169,State:1,Class:15
[17:00:55 INF] Request finished in 556.6788ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If I remove the `GroupBy` altogether it works (but I have duplicated data).
Am I doing something wrong? Why is it generating duplicate order by's? Why is it generating `Order By` at all? Does `Group By` translates to an order by?

More strange, this happened to a collegue. In my database this was working just fine. I asked her to make a dump for me to debug. In both cases we have no data on the `TrainMovementPlanned` table...

Comment: Have you taken a look on the on this error message: `A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.`

Comment: @TanvirArjel sure! Have you taken a look at my question? I searched for this error but couldn't find anything other than people ordering by twice or smth like that